# Azure AD OAuth2 - Skip account selection

Tags: azure, oauth, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am using Microsoft Azure AD and OAuth2 to get access token using authorization code:

1. Build login url and redirect to it

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?client_id=xxx&response_type=code&redirect_uri=yyyy&response_mode=query&scope=zzzz&state=1111`

2. Return from login page and get code
3. Get access token (POST)

`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token?client_id=xxxx&redirect_uri=yyyy&code=zzzz&grant_type=authorization_code&client_secret=1111`

Everything works just fine, but between steps 1 and 2 the end-user has to choose which account to use (see login screen pictures at the end).

**The user is always already logged in to login.microsoftonline.com at this point** and the consent to use the application has been granted by the admin to the whole organization.

**Question:**

Is there any way to skip this, for example with optional parameter indicating to automatically use account with @company.com suffix? Is it possible with the `common` tenant or even with a specific tenant?

**Goal:**

I have a group policy to open some web pages on startup and I want users automatically logged in to this website. Even one click ruins this. I am using PHP if it matters.

- old login screen:

[image]

- new login screen:

[image]

Comment: Do you always expect the user to be already signed in?

Comment: @GauravMantri 95% of the times, yes.

Comment: Can you try by including `prompt=none` in your request URL in step 1. However please keep in mind that if the user is not signed in, then the application will generate an error and you would need to handle that. More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code#request-an-authorization-code.

Comment: `prompt=none` doesn't seem to work even if I only have one account in the list and logged in. `domain_hint` did though!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `domain_hint` parameter (`domain_hint=company.com`):

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?domain_hint=company.com&client_id=xxx&response_type=code&redirect_uri=yyyy&response_mode=query&scope=zzzz&state=1111
```

More here:

http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/11/17/skipping-the-home-realm-discovery-page-in-azure-ad/

This works for v1 and v2 endpoints, unlike the documentation says.

Comment: I don't think this would work as Azure AD v2 endpoint is being used here and based on the documentation (link in my comment above), domain_hint can only take one of the following two values: `consumers` or `organizations`.

Comment: Ah, my bad. The authorize URL OP had was for v1 :)

Comment: Domain value for `domain_hint` seems to work with v2 too! Isn't documented though :) Thanks!

Comment: Wait what? The documentation is wrong? That could never happen :D